# How to use SharedPreferences to save a URI, or any Storage?

Tags: android

```
URI imageUri = null;

//Setting the Uri of aURL to imageUri.
try {
    imageUri = aURL.toURI();
} catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am using this code to translate a URL to a URI. How could I save the imageUri to a SharedPreferences, or a memory where it wouldnt be deleted onDestroy()?

I dont want to do SQLite database because the URI will change when the URL's change.I dont want to use up memory for unused URI's

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To get started using SharedPreferences for storage you'll need to have something like this in your onCreate():

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences(myTag, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor myPrefsEdit = myPrefs.edit();
```

I think you can do something like this to store it:

```
myPrefsEdit.putString("url", imageUri.toString());
myPrefsEdit.commit();
```

And then something like this to retrieve:

```
try {
    imageUri = URI.create(myPrefs.getString("url", "defaultString"));
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Any risk of encoding problems when saving Uri to sharedPrefs?

Comment: How can this be the answer when URI and Uri are not the same thing.

Answer (score 27):

You can just save a string representation of your URI.

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("imageURI", imageUri.toString()); <-- toString()
```

Then use the [Uri parse](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) method to retrieve it.

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
String imageUriString = settings.getString("imageURI", null);
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(imageUriString); <-- parse
```

Comment: In his example code he used the java.net.URI object which has .create(String) instead of .parse(String) like the android.net.Uri. Is there an upside to using one of these over the other?

Comment: I actually assumed android.net.Uri was what the OP was trying to save to shared preferences. If not, your answer is definitely the correct one.

Comment: I think they would both work, and I have never come across any any reasons for one over the other

Answer (score 0):

To save the uri as a preference you first need to translate it to a string using the getPath() method.  Then you can store it like this.

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("whateveryouwant", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = userSettings.edit();  
prefEditor.putString("key", uriString);  
prefEditor.commit();
```