# Whenever the activity gets killed or navigated to new activity the image disappears

Tags: java, android, imagepicker

I am trying to make an app where I can let a user select a picture to display on their profile. I am able to browse and set their selected image on imageview. But the image is lost once the the activity is destroyed. I tried to implement `onSaveInstanceState` but still it's the same. I'm wondering if I am using it correctly. I hope you can help a newbie like me. Thanks in advance. Here's the code that I'm using:
PS: I am using External library to Set image
Library I am using:-

```
implementation 'com.github.dhaval2404:imagepicker:2.1'
```

Main Activity code:-

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.github.dhaval2404.imagepicker.ImagePicker;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imageView;
    FloatingActionButton fab;
    Uri uri;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        fab = findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton1);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ImagePicker.with(MainActivity.this)
//                        .crop()                   //Crop image(Optional), Check Customization for more option
//                        .compress(1024)           //Final image size will be less than 1 MB(Optional)
//                        .maxResultSize(1080, 1080)    //Final image resolution will be less than 1080 x 1080(Optional)
                        .start();

            }
        });
        if(savedInstanceState != null){
            uri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("savedImage");
            imageView.setImageURI(uri);
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"No Image",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uri = data.getData();
        imageView.setImageURI(uri);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull @NotNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelable("savedImage",uri);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once image set to imageview store the uri to sharedprefs. something like this

```
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("myImage", uri);
 editor.apply();
```

than, replace your toast message something like this.

```
 Uri storedImage = URI.create(prefs.getString("myImage", null));
 imageView.setImageURI(storedImage);
```

Answer (score 1):

When the activity gets killed or navigated, the bundle data does not remain. It is usually used for orientation changes mainly. It does not persist through out.

If you need something that persists, I would suggest to save it in SharedPreferences instead, although you would not be able to directly save it. You would need to convert the URI to string.

Here you can see some further reference

[How to use SharedPreferences to save a URI, or any Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169485/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-to-save-a-uri-or-any-storage)